# Did I fix this E-R diagram correctly?

Tags: database, diagram

I have a homework question which consists of a scenario with a given E-R diagram that needs to be corrected by applying the given instructions in the scenario. Can someone help me determine if I've fixed it correctly?

> A center  called ITARD do employing for Researchers(R), Research Assistants (RAs) and Administrators (A).
>   The information that should kept for each employee are [ FName , MName , LName , Bdate , Gender , Address , Phone , Mobile , date of joined , date of left]
>
> The information that should kept for each Project are [ Title, its description , start date , planned end date , actual end date , total planned budget , the PI ( principle investigator) ,The RAs and whom each is assigned]
>
> These are the requirement that should be represented in the E-R diagram
>
> 1. At the same Time, Each researcher may work on one or more active research projects.
> 2. A researcher not working on any active research projects may engage in any number of unsponsored research project with or without collaboration from the other researchers and in each case , they are not aided by any RA.
> 3. Researchers can collaborate on research projects, but there must be one PI (principle Investigator) designed each project.
> 4. Each Research Assistant (RA) is assigned to work on one or more projects.
> 5. Each (RA) is supervised be exactly one researcher for each research project the RA works on.
> 6. Since (RAs) are hired on research projects, no RA can be left without assigned tasks in one or more research projects.
> 7. Each project must be administered by one Administrator. Additionally, each administrator is supervised by one supervisor (another administrator)

I have solved this question, but need to be sure of my solution. Have I made any mistakes?  (The image links to a larger version.)

[image]

Comment: @Brad: All questions that are too vague and neither show effort or what has been tried (thus asking about specific confusion) are frowned upon, but we [don't need the homework tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812) to tell us that.

Comment: i have posted my answer as an image link along with original ERD and  i did my best to answer it because it is my first course in database, i have abstracted the scenario as i understand it . The question is not vague , it is clear and just i need to be sure of my answer .finally , thanks to modifying the title of the thread it is clear now